# Paper_clip s3 - application/octet-stream?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, mime-types

All my rails paper_clip images are being uploaded to Rails as "application/octet-stream"

Which is casuing issues.

How in Rails do I set the content/type to the right type? Image/png etc, based on the actual image being uploaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, in general you can always detect the proper mime-type from the uploaded file itself by using 'mime/types':

```
# Controller

def create
  @photo = Photo.new(:upload_file => params[:photo][:image])
  ...
end

# Model

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base  
  require 'mime/types'
  ...
  def upload_file=(data)
    data.content_type = MIME::Types.type_for(data.original_filename).to_s
    self.image = data
  end 
end
```

Comment: Seems to be errors? "NoMethodError (undefined method `original_filename' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x107b730b0>):
  app/models/photo.rb:29:in `swfupload_file='
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:15:in `upload'
  app/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:14:in `call'
"

Comment: Are you sure, you are passing the filename as photo[image] ('fileDataName': 'photo[image]') ? If thats the case, try to running the stack in debug mode and place "debugger" as the first call in the upload_file method. Then you can inspect data object.